# Convert duration of google maps distance service to minutes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using google maps distance matrix service that returns the `duration` as string in the format like:

- 50 minutes
- 1 hour 40 minutes
- 1 day 2 hours 20 minutes

For further processing I want all these string values to be converted in minutes. Looked for existing conversion plugins but didn't find any. Is there an easy way to do this conversion?

Comment: yes there is, its called math :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro), the `duration` property has two attributes : `text` and `value`. The `value` attribute returns the time in seconds. You can easily get the minutes from that value.

Sample response:

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "duration": {
    "value": 340110,
    "text": "3 jours 22 heures"
}
```

You can do something like:

```
 console.log((duration.value)/60); //Returns duration in minutes.
```